# OSPF: What's the consequence of two nssa area translator router

Tags: routing, ospf, protocol-theory

If NSSA area has 2 ABR, then usually one of them will be elected to be translator by router id. But what if I have 2 translator routers and both translate the message simultaneously? How to route in this situation? and is there any consequence of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to route in this situation?

Routing happens the same way as a regular area with multiple ABRs advertising the same prefix. Routers install the routes with the lowest metrics in the routing table. Remember that routing protocols do not route, they are used to exchange routing information, and each router makes its own decision on what gets installed in its routing table.

> is there any consequence of this situation?

What *[RFC 3101, The OSPF Not-So-Stubby Area (NSSA) Option](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3101)* says:

> Excessive numbers of Type-7 translators unnecessarily increase the
> size of the OSPF link state data base.